# Как оптимально совместить GULP с приложением на node js

Tags: node.js, gulp

Пишу приложение на node js и хочу для этого же проекта настроить GULP. Точно не знаю, как оптимально организовать структуру.

Надумал сделать так: внешняя папка GULP со своим PACKAGE.JSON, в ней размещаю папку приложения APP со своим PACKAGE.JSON. Вместо папки PUBLIC размещаю папку BUILD, в которую буду выгружать файлы из папки SRC. Папку BUILD сделаю static. В GULP установлю пакет *concurrency* и буду запускать GULP.JS совместно с APP.JS.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, приемлема ли такая структура для того, чтобы я мог спокойно писать приложение APP, держать его запущенным, открытым в браузере и в, то же время, писать вёрстку на препроцессоре scss, и чтобы она автоматически выгружалась в папку BUILD?

[image: Предполагаемая структура папок]

Comment: А скажите великий смысол создания нескольких файлов package.json? Он же хранит зависимости для проекта, устанавливает различные конфиги, точку входа и прочее. И по моему они не склеиваются. Зачем вам тогда их два? Можете попробовать держать один package.json в корневой папке, там же складывать gulp.config.js и все остальные конфиги линтеры и настройки. В src держать весь основной код в папке build сборку. В src добавить public. fonts, sass и тд

Comment: На самом деле не знаю, но видел такой вариант использования в видео-уроке [Full Stack eCommerce Cart build (React, Redux, Node, Express, MongoDB)...From Scratch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0divhP3pEsg&t=11901s). Там показана разработка магазина на реакте и бэкэнда к нему. И поскольку там две точки входа, то автор рекомендовал такой вариант. Я же хочу узнать, в случае с gulp это будет приемлемое решение или нужно как-то подругому.

Comment: возможно он разделил свое приложение на front и back. Отсюда такая архитектура. Используйте вариант попроще до тех пор, пока не будет надобности в варианте посложнее

Comment: У меня тоже получается две точки входа: app.js (бэкэнд-приложение) и gulp.js. Это можно описать в одном файле package.json?